# What can cause a control to not be re-drawn in C#

Tags: c#, invalidation

I use a TreeView to display data with winform and .Net 4.5.. Sometimes it's not repainted when I add a node. In order to force the repaint, I use `this.invalidates()` and `this.update()` but it's not working. I added a PaintEventHandler in order to see if `Paint()` is called :

```
    DefaultConstructor(){
        [...]
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.OnThisPaint);
    }

    private void OnThisPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("repaint");
    }

    private void updateTree()
    {
        //Some fabulous code
        Console.WriteLine("Updating the tree");
        
        try
        {
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in invalidate");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And sometimes the paint is not called, which cause wrong display. No error is thrown even when the control isn't repainted.

### Edit :

Here's the output I get :

```
'Sakura.UI.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Microsoft.GeneratedCode'
Bubble Graph // <- Start of the treeview
Cycle Graph
Line Graph
   Flw_OilConc_Graph
   Spec_OilConc_Graph
   WorkingExample
Stacked Graph
   ELR_Smoke_Test
   Full Load p.1
   Spec_Oil_Graph
Table
Table APM
Table Dura // <- Start of the treeview
invalidated
repaint
'Sakura.UI.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\TFS\2014\Source_LYS\Source-1\Sakura II\Projects\Sakura.UI\bin\Debug\Sakura.UI.Reporting.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Sakura.UI.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Microsoft.GeneratedCode'
'Sakura.UI.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\TFS\2014\Source_LYS\Source-1\Sakura II\Projects\Sakura.UI\bin\Debug\Sakura.DataCoordinating.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Sakura.UI.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\TFS\2014\Source_LYS\Source-1\Sakura II\Projects\Sakura.UI\bin\Debug\Sakura.Reporting.dll', Symbols loaded.
invalidated
'Sakura.UI.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Volvo Powertrain\Sakura\Evaluations\Sakura.Eval.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Sakura.UI.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Microsoft.GeneratedCode'
repaint
repaint
Bubble Graph // <- Start of the treeview
Cycle Graph
Line Graph
   Flw_OilConc_Graph
   Spec_OilConc_Graph
   UnworkingExample // <- Undisplayed node
   WorkingExample
Stacked Graph
   ELR_Smoke_Test
   Full Load p.1
   Spec_Oil_Graph
Table
Table APM
Table Dura // <- End of the treeview
invalidated
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x1620) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xed4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**What can cause such a behavior ?**

Comment: You dont need update for repainting and you also dont need a paint event if you arent gonna do anything in it. Other then that, the error might be because a uncought exception happens in your updateTree() before this.Invalidate() try puting all the code in updateTree() in a try catch block and print out every error to console in catch statment or i na messagebox

Comment: @Vajura I use a paintEvent to see if `paint()` is called. I'll go try the try/catch

Comment: Yea just wrote it incase you though it did something else.

Comment: @Vajura is the edit sounds better now ?

Comment: Keep an eye on the Output window to see what exception(s) might be thrown when that happens.  You can then instruct the IDE to always break on that exception type and get more information about exactly what's happening at the time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney not exception is thrown...

Comment: @Thomas, are you sure about that?  It doesn't say anything about a first-chance exception in the Output window?

Comment: @jmcilhinney here's full log (see edit)

Comment: Do you add the node while handling a UI event? Sometimes if too many UI changes occur rapidly, the Paint event will not be raised.

Comment: @groverboy I don't know : the user press a button "add node" which update the treeview. This is not an UI event, isn't it ?

Comment: @Thomas: this begs for a better code example. Since updates to a control normally _do_ cause an update automatically, something's interfering with that, and it's obviously something in code other than what you posted. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes a button click _is_ a UI event, like _any_ user action on the UI. So there are at least 2 UI updates: press button, add TreeView node. I suggest you set a breakpoint on the method that updates the TreeView for "UnworkingExample". When the debugger stops on the breakpoint, check the call stack to look for other methods that update the UI at the same time. You could post the call stack and/or the TreeView update method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to poor implementation, the control displayed was not the one modified. That's why paint was not called.